# B-52s that are not in service demolished?

Tags: military

Have all the B-52s that are no longer in service already been "guillotined," i.e. chopped in two to make them no longer flyable?

Answer (score 3):

No, some B-52H's in long term storage at the [Aerospace Maintenance and Regeneration Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/309th_Aerospace_Maintenance_and_Regeneration_Group) are in Type 1000 storage, which means,

> Aircraft stored in near-flyaway condition. Can be stored without re-preservation for a period of 4 years. Aircraft stored under this category may be downgraded to Type 2000.

[image: B-52s in AMRG]

Note: This screengrab is from Google Maps and I'm not sure when it was taken.

The USAF is under the process of [reclaiming a B-52H](https://medium.com/war-is-boring/i-ll-be-damned-these-boneyard-b-52s-can-still-fly-4eec4c8bf5cf) from the Boneyard as a replacement.

[image: B 52H Ghost Rider]

Source: foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com

However, [all the B-52G models have been destroyed](http://www.militarytimes.com/article/20131228/NEWS04/312280002/Last-B-52G-eliminated-under-nuclear-arms-treaty) in compliance with the [New START](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_START) treaty.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, according to this picture of the [Boneyard](http://www.cnn.com/2012/06/08/travel/aviation-enthusiast-destinations/) there are still some intact full airframes (I believe those are B-52's)

[image] 
([source](http://www.cnn.com/2012/06/08/travel/aviation-enthusiast-destinations/))

For what its worth chopping an airframe in half only makes it no longer flyable in its current state. While it may sound crazy that is actually not an impossible thing to repair as long is its done properly. You can see some of the planes chopped up in the photo but I would assume that was done to either transport them to the boneyard (they were un-flyable) or they are going to be shipped out to fix another plane.

Comment: The photo is at least a few years old but they're probably not all gone yet.

Comment: Fair enough, but id say it provides some solid evidence they are at least not chopped up directly upon retirement.

Comment: It not only makes it unflyable in its current state, it makes it *obviously* unflyable in a way that even satellite photos can verify. Since the B-52s are implicated by arms control treaties, this is useful.